# How to send email from "no-reply@mycompany.com" with python and win32com outlook

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I want that the person who will receive the email, see that the email was sent from no-reply@mycompany.com
I've tried to send with the parameter message.SendOnBehalfOfName but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
> import win32com.Client as client
outlook=client.Dispatch("outlook.Application")

#start sending email

message.outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.SendOnBehalfOfName = "no-reply@mycompany.com"
message.To = "tocustomer@blabla.com"
message.Subject ="test"
message.HTMLBody="test"

message.Send()
```

The code is working only if I remove the line message.SendOnBehalf....
The email then is sent by the account that I have preconfigured in outlook.
The customer is receiving the email from "myname@mycompay.com"

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Do you get any error messages if you try to use SendOnBehalfOfName? My best bet is permissions on your Exchange / M365

Comment: "The code is working only if I remove the line message.SendOnBehalf" Okay, and when you have that line, **how** does it not work? What **happens** with that code? If there is an error message, [show the complete error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). Also, what did the documentation tell you? Are you sure `SendOnBehalfOfName` is the correct name?

Comment: As an aside, did you [consider other approaches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+send+email) to sending email, rather than trying to communicate with the Outlook program?

Comment: The error is the following:
AttributeError:Property 'CreateItem.SendOnBehalfOfName' cannot to be set

Comment: In that case it seems that that argument is wron. In Exchange Send of behalf refers usually to account, not a name.

Comment: Are you the owner of the no-reply account? If not, then the documentation suggests you need to have delegate permissions on the no-reply account in order to create and send messages from that address.